# How the repositroy in springboot3 injecr to the @service class

Tags: service, spring-data-jpa

here is the sample code

```
@Service
public class TodoServiceImpl implements TodoService {
    
    TodoRepository todoRepository;  

    @Override
    public TodoDto addTodo(TodoDto todoDto) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String deleteTodo(Long todoId) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

why  todoRepository  dosen't need @Autowired or @Resource to tell ioc inject

the core content about this question

Comment: If you will try to get some information from repository, i mean invoke  a query it is going to be a NullPointerException